# Adjusting multiple materials at once

Tags: materials

just wanna ask is there a way to you can manipulate the multiple materials in one object at once?

For example there are two materials on this sphere, I want apply another shader to the material, but I want the same shader to all other materials that contains it's own texture. Is there a ways [image: to apply the shader all at once instead of doing one by one?]
This is just an example sphere, the mesh I will need to apply has contain large amount of materials in one object.

Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a node group: Select your 2 nodes (*Glossy BSDF* and *Mix Shader*) and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>. It will automatically display what's inside the group. To exit press <kbd>Tab</kbd> (and to enter again press <kbd>Tab</kbd> again). To create the same group in another material press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *NodeGroupName*. To ungroup, select the group and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>.

[image]